# How do I make a well designed validation for a complex collection model?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

As input I have a list of Books. As output I expect a SimilarBookCollection.

A SimilarBookCollection has an author, publishYear and list of Books. The SimilarBookCollection can't be created if the author of the books is different or if the publishYear is different.

The solution so far in PHP:

```
client.php
----
$arrBook = array(...); // array of books
$objValidator = new SimilarBookCollectionValidator($arrBook);
if ($objValidator->IsValid()) {
   $objSimilarBookCollection = new SimilarBookCollection($arrBook);
   echo $objSimilarBookCollection->GetAuthor();
}
else {
   echo 'Invalid input';
}


SimilarBookCollection.php
---
class SimilarBookCollection() {
 public function SimilarBookCollection(array $arrBook) { 
       $objValidator = new SimilarBookCollectionValidator($arrBook); 
       if ($objValidator->IsValid()) {
         throw new Exception('Invalid books to create collection');
       }
       $this->author = $arrBook[0]->GetAuthor();
       $this->publishYear = $arrBook[0]->GetPublishYear();
       $this->books = $arrBook;
 }
 public function GetAuthor() {
      return $this->author;
 }

 public function GetPublishYear() {
      return $this->publishYear;
 }

 public function GetBooks() {
      return $this->books;
 }
}

SimilarBookCollectionValidator.php
---
class SimilarBookCollectionValidator() {
 public function IsValid() {
   $this->ValidateAtLeastOneBook();
   $this->ValidateSameAuthor();
   $this->ValidateSameYear();

   return $this->blnValid;
 }

 ... //actual validation routines
}
```

**The goal is to have a "special" collection with only books that have the same author and publishYear. The idea is to easily access the repeating information like author or year from the object.**

- How would you name the SimilarBookCollection? The current name is to
  generic. Using a name like SameYearAuthorBookCollection looks a bit
  long and strange(if more conditions will be added then name will increase)
- Would you use a Validator in SimilarBookCollection constructor using a
  defensive programming style?
- Would you change the design of the code? If yes how?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends ;)

So if I were to aim for a **generic adaptable solution** I would do the following:

**Validator in constructor**
On one hand you are validating twice; that is informative in case of a broken precondition/contract (not giving a valid list), but is double the code to run - for what purpose exactly?
If you want to use this in a system depends on its size, how critical it is, product phase, and likely more criterias.
But then it also is controller logic fitted into a model meaning you are spreading your code around.

I would not put it in the constructor.

**Name / Design**
I would say keep the BookCollection generic as it is, and have any validation strictly in the controller space, instead of bloating the collection which essentially seems to be an array with the extra field of author.

If you want to differentiate between different collection types use either (multiple) inheritance or some sort of additional field "collectionType"; the former if you expect many derivatives or varying functionality to come (also keeps the logic where different nicely separated).

You could also consider your collection as a set on which you perform queries and for convenience's sake you could maintain some sort of meta data like $AuthorCount = N, $publicationDates = array(...) from which you can quickly derive the collection's nature. This approach would also keep your validator-code minimal (or non-existent), as it'd be implicitly in the collection and you could just do the validation in the controller keeping the effective logic behind it clearly visible.

That would also make it more comfortable for you in the future. But the question really is what you want and need it for, and what changes you expect, because you are supposed to fit your design to your requirements and likely changes.

For your **very particular problem** the constraints as I understand are as follows:

1. There is only one collection type class in the system at any given
   point in time.
2. The class's items have several attributes, and for a particular, possibly changing subset of these (called identical attributes), the collection only accepts item lists where the chosen attributes of all items are identical.
3. The class provides getters for all identical attributes
4. The class must not be usable in any other way than the intended way.

If not for point 1 I would use a generic base class that is either parametrized (ie you tell it upon instantiation which is the set of identical attributes) or uses multiple inheritance (or in php traits) to compose arbitrary combinations with the needed interfaces. Children might rely on the base class but use a predefined subset of the identical attributes.

The parametrized variant might look something as follows:

```
class BookCollection {
    public function __construct($book_list, $identical_fields=array())
    {
         if (empty($book_list))
         {
             throw new EmptyCollectionException("Empty book list");
         }

         $default = $book_list[0];
         $this->ia = array();
         foreach($identical_fields as $f)
         {
              $this->ia[$f] = $default->$f;
         }

         foreach($book_list as $book)
         {
              foreach($identical_fields as $f)
              {
                   if ($this->ia[$f] !== $book->$f)
                   {
                        throw new NotIdenticalFieldException("Field $f is not identical for all");
                   }
               }
          }

          $this->book_list = $book_list;
    }
    public function getIdentical($key)
    {
        $this->ia[$key];
    }
}

final class BC_by_Author extends BookCollection{
    public function __construct($book_list)
    {
        parent::__construct($book_list,array('author'));
    }

    public function getAuthor(){ $this->ia['author']; }
}
```

or fooling around with abstract and final types (not sure if it's valid like this)

```
abstract class BookCollection{
    public final function __construct($book_list){...}
    abstract public function getIdenticalAttributes();
}
final class BC_by_Author {
    public function getIdenticalAttributes(){ return array('author'); }
    public function getAuthor(){ return $this->ia['author']; }
}
```

If you rely on getters that do not necessarily match the field names I would go for multiple inheritance/traits.
The naming then would be something like BC_Field1Field2Field3.

Alternatively or additionally, you could also use exactly the same classname but develop your solutions in different namespaces, which would mean you wouldn't have to change your code when you change the namespace, plus you can keep it short in the controllers.

But because there will only ever be one class, I would name it BookCollection and not unnecessarily discuss it any further.

Because of constraint 4, the white box constraint, the given book list must be validated by the class itself, ie in the constructor.

Comment: This is the important line: $objBookCollection->GetAuthor(), if the books don't have the same attributes then you can't extract the Author from the collection.

Comment: If I just let the BookCollection class without Validation any developer can see it and instantiate it with an array of books that don't have the same characteristics.